# Is there a way to make a docker container create a virtual nic on the host's network?

Tags: networking, docker

I'm new to docker and I'm playing with the network options.
bridge networks makes a private network and bridges it to the host's network.

The host network uses the host machine's network stack, your docker processes live in the same network space as processes on the host machine.

What I'm looking for is something like what virtualbox does when it makes a what it calls a bridged network adapter. It is a peer of the host's network but the interface is separate and can get its own ip address from the network's dhcp server.

Does functionality like that exist in docker? I can't find it, if it does.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does functionality like that exist in docker?

No.

Comment: well there ya go